# How to track status code of logic apps

Tags: azure, logic, http-status-code-404, azure-logic-apps

I want to track status code of a entire logic app instead of particular action status code using expression.

Status Code would be mention in tracked properties of a logic app.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

You can check status using below expression code

```
@int(actionOutputs('ActionName').statusCode)
```

Then you can check that code using condition like in below picture

[image: Conditions]

If You have any more questions related to feel free to ask

Comment: The question is how to track the global status of the logic app not a particular action....

Comment: Thank You for your answer . But I want the entire logic app status .. not for a particular action

Comment: Thanks. That worked. actually you dont get clue by looking at the action's output statusCode value as it already shows it as integer.

Answer (score 0):

Stay tuned.  In a couple of days, I will be publishing an article on how to know the status of a running Logic App.  Will update this Answer once it's posted.

And it's here:
[Knowing the State of Your Logic App Process](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51261.knowing-the-state-of-your-logic-app-process.aspx)

Comment: @DisaryNathSarkar  Thanks for the reminder.  There you go!

Answer (score 0):

you can track entire logic app staus using Operations Management Suite (OMS) and Log Analytics

its give you entire logic app in details status please check below link

[Please check for OMS details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-monitor-your-logic-apps-oms)